# Put object into S3 bucket works, but only at the bucket level, not inside folders with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to convert a large file to Athena partitions inside of S3. I'm able to write the objects at the bucket level, but not able to place them into folders. Is the formatting of my "obj" variable below correct?

```
    obj = "json/clicks/clickpartition/clicks_"+date+".json"
    try:
        s3.Object("my-bucket", obj).load()
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == '404':
            s3.Object('my-bucket', obj).put(Body=daily)
            print("Uploaded "+str(obj))
        else:
            print(e.response)
```

I have also tried with a / at the beginning of the obj string.

EDIT: I do not get any errors, the code runs and prints the output line, but no file is there in the bucket/folder. Pushing to just the bucket works fine.

Comment: Could you clarify which line is giving the error, and provide the specific wording of the error? It is only failing on the `put()` line?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It does not look to be failing. I added that print line after the put, and I get that output, so it seems to be running it just fine, but there is no file in S3 when I check. If I remove the path and just put the object directly in the bucket, it works.

Comment: Have you try s3 client with upload_file?  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file

Comment: Would it possibly be because the two bucket names are different? I presume you changed the bucket name for this Question, but it was only changed in one location in the code.

Comment: The path of an object should have _no_ impact on whether it successfully uploads (unless maybe there are bad characters in the Key). You should do more experimenting and debugging because the behaviour you describe should not be happening.